# Two different interfaces for AWS Tag Editor?

Tags: amazon-web-services

It seems that there are two different Web UI for AWS Tag Editor (you need an AWS account to try them):

1. https://resources.console.aws.amazon.com/r/tags

   - I got this link from [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/tag-editor.html)
2. https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/tag-editor/find-resources?region=eu-west-1

   - In Management Console, if you select `Resource Group` > `Tag Editor` on the top of the console page, it will take you to this page

The two WebUI behave differently:

1. The former is global but the latter is region-specific (it will put you into a region even if you don't put the `region` parameter in the URL)
2. The former allows you to search for `Not tagged` in the filter; but the latter does not
3. The UI are slightly different

Is one of UI a newer version?

**Update (2019-05-14)**

(Please also see an explanation about the two links being NEW and OLD UIs that AWS offered at a certain point in time) By now the first link is gone.  If you visit it, you will get a `404 Not Found` error from AWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am part of the team building the new Tag Editor. Yes, you are correct: Classic Tag Editor is deprecated, and will be shut down soon entirely. We are working on full feature parity between the two Editors, so you will very soon find everything you can do in the old one as well in the new one.

To add some more context on your different items below:

1) Both old and new Tag Editor use the same underlying tagging infrastructure, so this should never happen. Maybe there is some browser issue involved here? Feel free to open a support issue so we can look deeper into it, if this continues the case.

2) Yes, the new one also includes Lambda, and will very soon add more resource types. The same by the way for regions: The old Tag Editor supports not all regions, for example `eu-north-1` or `eu-west-3`.

3) No, Route53 Hosted Zones are supported in both Editors. Route53 resources only exists in the `us-east-1` region, so maybe you used the Tag Editor in another region?

4) Both Editors show the same data. The old editor merged what you used as Name Tag and the ID in the same field - in the new one, you see only the ID in the column ID, and the Name Tag is displayed in the column `Tag: Name`.

Searching across regions is something the new Editor soon will support, too, and the same applies for the filter you mention. For showing resources without a specific tag, there is a workaround you already can do: Click on the settings icon in the top right of the table, and enable the tag you are interested in as a column. You then can sort this column so that all untagged ones show up on top.

If you have any other ideas or requests for the Tag Editor, please let us know. The fastest and most reliable way is to just use the 'Feedback' Button in the console in the bottom left.

Cheers,
Florian

Comment: And now the original tag editor is gone (404). However, some major features are missing, especially the ability to find resources for a tag that have no value (which is critical use)

Comment: Sorry for responding so late, but this is available since several months now, I hope you now find everything you need. The easiest way to give feedback here is to use the 'Feedback' button in the lower left of the console, we monitor this on an ongoing basis, and it also helps us to reach out to you if we have follow up questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am providing my own answer here (thanks my colleagues Kannan for the insight)

`#1` above is what AWS called `Class Tag Editor`.  If you click on the Question mark on the Web UI (upper right corner), you will be taken to a page that says:

> This documentation is for classic Tag Editor, which has been
>   deprecated

So `#2` is the version that AWS want us to use.

Below I will called `#1` **Old** and `#2` **New**

I compared the example outputs from our environment (about 50 resources).  The two outputs differ in these respects:

1. **New** seems to retain past resources for a longer time.  For example, if an EC2 instance has been terminated, it may take a
   longer time to be removed from the listing of **New**
2. **New** seems to include resources for DynamoDB but **Old** does not
3. **Old** seems to include resources for Route 53 Hosted Zones but **New** does not.
4. Both **New** and **Old** show Security Groups, but the ID strings are rendered slightly differently.

   - **New** renders an ID as `sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
   - **Old** renders an ID as `someName (sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)`